# Edit kubectl namespace label with ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, istio

I need to enable istio injection in Ansible. My command is,

`kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled`

I want to run this command in Ansible. I used the ansible `k8s` module for this task. But it keeps errors.

```
  k8s:
    name: default
    kind: Namespace
    label: istio-injection=enabled
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Ansible to modify a Kubernetes object in-place (with the exception that you can [`k8s_scale`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_scale_module.html#k8s-scale-module) a deployment).  The flip side of this is that a [Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#namespace-v1-core) is an ordinary Kubernetes object, so you can use [`k8s`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html#k8s-module) to create or update it.  There's no facility to just specify the object metadata so you need to give a fairly complete object description.  (You would need to know *all* of the namespace labels, if you have more than just the Istio label.)

```yaml
k8s:
  state: present
  definition:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Namespace
    metadata:
      name: default
      labels:
        'istio-injection': enabled
```

Comment: You could patch the existing namespace also with `state: patched`